# Redux-Form Understanding Multipage Form Ajax PUT

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, react-redux, redux-form

**Preface:**
I'm a rails developer that is familiar enough with Javascript to write basic things but my overall understanding of the frameworks in question react + react-redux + redux-form may be insufficient. I'm still working on that.

**Task to Accomplish:**
I'm trying to implement a multiple page form using redux-form.  I have the multiple page form working.  I now need to post all three pages of the wizard's values in one XHR request.

**The Problem:**
I'm following the example of the multipage Wizard form in the redux-form documentation: http://redux-form.com/4.2.0/#/examples/wizard?_k=h898k7

However, I don't seem to understand where an XHR request should be handled.  This may be a fundamental misunderstanding of react and react-redux.  I see they have an onSubmit function passed to each wizard page from WizardForm.js parent component, but I don't think I understand where WizardForm.js is getting that onSubmit function nor what the shape of that function would be if the goal is to accomplish an XHR PUT request on WizardFormThirdPage.js.

Also, though the goal of the form submission isn't (yet) to change any of the redux store's state, would it be rational to make an action that does the XHR when something is dispatched like 'SUBMIT_FORM'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> would it be rational to make an action that does the XHR when
>   something is dispatched like 'SUBMIT_FORM'?

Absolutely! Actions don't have to return objects like `{ type: FOO }`, they can also return functions, and that makes life a little easier when you want to do XHR stuff: http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html.

As for the other parts of your question, if you don't follow the async actions path, the ajax requests can theoretically be done pretty much everywhere, but the highest central point that makes sense in the component hierarchy is usually better. In your case there's no reason the WizardForm component shouldn't take care of that. WizardForm also has to keep track of the values entered in the three pages, unless...

**If you already use Redux to store that data, then you're good to go** - just consume the store, if not you have to pass a function from WizardForm to each individual page that's responsible for updating WizardForm's local state.

In the pseudo example below you can see how I pass the function onSetPageValue to the wizard page, and use this to change WizardForm's state. In the example you posted, WizardForm gets this function from a place higher up in the chain, but the principle is the same, and this concept is fundamental to React.

```
class WizardForm extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.onHandleSubmit = this.onHandleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.onSetPageValue = this.onSetPageValue.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      pageValues: {
        1: '',
        2: ''
      }
    }
  }
  onHandleSubmit () {
    /* Do all xhr stuff, update state/store/whatever fits your application */
  }
  onSetPageValue(page, value){
    this.setState({
      pageValues: Object.assign({}, this.state.pageValues, {[page]:value})
    });
  }
  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <WizardPage1 onSetPageValue={this.onSetPageValue}/>
        <button onClick={this.onHandleSubmit}>Submit</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class WizardPage1 extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <button onClick={() => {this.props.onSetPageValue(1, 'Foo!')}}>Trigger onSetPageValue</button>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You, sir, are a godsend.

Comment: @dannyjolie Wouldn't you get 2 buttons in this scenario ?